# pscp copy file remotely from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

I need to copy file from my Windows XP system to remote Linux system.

Win location : `c:\1.txt`
LInux location:`/tmp`

What should be the command?

***EDITED:*** pscp is recognized and OK on my PC.I CAN connect with Putty to this remote Linux PC
remote Linux name is `s1`,hostname is `s1host`

I tried transfer file with following command:

```
pscp C:\1.txt s1@s1host:/tmp
```

Got:`Fatal: Network error: Connection timed out`

It's not clear,is command isn't ok?

Comment: What have you tried?  Running `pscp /?` will tell you how to run it.  Or is `pscp` not found?

Comment: @Mikel i've updated question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
pscp c:\1.txt username@hostname:/tmp
```

Substitute `username` and `hostname` for those valid for the Linux system.

Comment: i've updated question, tried as you said and got connection timed out

Comment: That's because your windows PC can't connect to your Linux host for some reason - is ssh at the remote end running on a non standard port? If so you'll also need to use the -P portnumber specificatoon.

Comment: remote PC port is 2222

Comment: Then use pscp -P 2222 c:\1.txt username@hostname:/tmp

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the drive letter.  The colon character in the drive letter makes pscp think you mean host:path, on a host named C.  You can change to that drive letter, then not specify the drive letter on your windows path:

```
c:
pscp \1.txt s1@s1host:/tmp
```