# Extracting files from windows to linux on a same partition

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, fedora, file-transfer

First Hello.

I'm having a little stupid issue that comes to me when i installed Fedora 20 on my laptop.

Before installing the Fedora i had Windows 7 on my C: partition. The laptop is with 700 GB hard drive devided on 2 partitions - C: (102GB) and D: (the rest - approximately 600 GB). So before i had about an year ago i had only Fedora on the laptop but i had to format the hard drive and install windows cause of university project. Since i have format the C: partition and installed windows 7 i have made some files usefull to me. I'v red somewhere that i can install the both operation systems on one partition and i remember done it before without any problems. I'v formated the partition to xfs file sustem and the installation of fedora was successful. So now when i'v installed fedora after the windows 7 on the same partition C: but something went wrong. I can't use the windows, when i try to start it up from the list when the pc is starting and choose it i'm getting message ''error 0xc7000000 or something similiar( i can't remember it exactly right now). I'v tried to fix it with ''windows system repair disc'' but no success. I don't bother much about the windows OS right now, i use my fedora and study it with interest but i had a file in the windows OS that i really need. So my exactly question is can i extract that specific file( it is a simple notepad text document with some java code and some other writings that i value) true the fedora. I remember that the text document was at the desktop of the windows. I'm thinking from something true the terminal showing the content of files in that partition and move it to my home directory or on flash drive for examp. With the lsblk command i see this result :

```
 NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
    ├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part /run/media/jinx/711a8f8c-9760-4d4f-9b66-bb27ffb58093
    ├─sda2   8:2    0   3.1G  0 part /run/media/jinx/3E2A9FF92A9FAC81
    ├─sda3   8:3    0 592.6G  0 part /run/media/jinx/New Volume
    ├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
    ├─sda5   8:5    0   500M  0 part /run/media/jinx/cc98d7f8-ada4-4e9f-8354-800274322e2b
└─sda6   8:6    0 101.6G  0 part /
```

As long as i know the desktop of windows is in c\documents and settings\all users\desktop , and it is in the sda6 101.6G part.

But here is where i stuck. I don't know any command that can show all the files in the partition(including thouse of the old os(windows) and i don't know is there a way to copy that specific file and move it elsewhere.

Another idea that i had in mind was to reformat again the partition to NTFS fs and again try using the ''windows system repair disk''

That is it, and advices will be welcome. Thx in advance

p.p v found this topics but i'm not sure they are exactl related to my problem.
Pls tell me if i'm missing something.

[copy file from windows to Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/562702/copy-file-from-windows-to-linux)

[pscp copy file remotely from Windows to Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/256259/pscp-copy-file-remotely-from-windows-to-linux)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  Because your exact wording is not possible.  How many partitions does the physical disk have exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming windows is in /dev/sda6 and intact, mount the windows partision readonly like:

```
mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sda6 /mnt/win
```

This also requires linux system to have ntfs filesystem support.

might need to create /mnt/win beforehand

```
mkdir -p /mnt/win
```

running as admin or add *sudo* before each of those commands

The windows system should then appear in /mnt/win

Comment: i try it and it give; message @Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command."

Comment: Thx fot your reply.      i'v give it a try and i see this message - @Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
@. I checked the /mntwin dir with the ls command but nothing is shown. eny suggestations about that ?

Comment: try just "mount" for a list of already mounted partitions, maybe it's already mounted elsewhere

Comment: thx Joakim, when i app; the command i see big list, i tryed to mount the only dev i dont see in the list sda4 but no result and when i checked i saw it's just 1k. the list is with alot of things i don't know about. for exam - /dev/sda6 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota) the terms seclable attr2 and the others don't talk nothing to me. If you know what i must be looking for(the term that has something to do with windows) pls explain.

Comment: Joakim i found solution, thx for your replays and posts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install two systems to the same partition. I believe what you mean is you have two partitions on one volume/disk. Did you try to install Fedora on the C: or D: partition?

To recover files, you can use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download). I've used that a few times to recover files from a corrupted Windows partition.

Comment: Thx for your reply to but Joakim gaved me a good solution, the testdisk as long as i know is for recovering deleted files, but my file was not deleted, it existed on the windows desktop. Anyway thx afain.   Regards

Comment: Sure no problem. As long as your problem was resolved, that's great.